# Express.js: Setting a cookie through a login with discord system not working

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

So I am building a dashboard for my bot, and I am having issues logging into this dashboard with Discord. I am using a secondary server for the express functionality, and then sending it to my domain, as the domain provider only allows static html.

Anyway, I tried sending it with `res.cookie`, but it would just return undefined. I even checked the "Application" tab for the cookie, it was not there.

```js
app.get('/callback', async (req, res) => {
    const code = req.query.code;

    try {
      const tokenResponse = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams({
          client_id: CLIENT_ID,
          client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
          code: code,
          grant_type: 'authorization_code',
          redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
          scope: 'identify guilds',
        }),
      });
  
      const tokenData = await tokenResponse.json();
      const accessToken = tokenData.access_token;

      const userResponse = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/users/@me', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      });
  
      const userData = await userResponse.json();

      const id = userData.id

//this is just the debugging, eventualy it will be encrypted.

      res.cookie('userId', id, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: false, path: '/', domain: 'example.com' });
      res.redirect('https://example.com/dashboard');

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during OAuth2 callback:', error.message);
      console.error('Api Response: ', error.response ? await error.response.json() : 'No response data');
      res.status(500).send('Error during OAuth2 callback');
    }
  });
```

When I set the cookie myself manualy, it worked!

Any help is greatly appreciated!